# How download json file on button click in vue js app

Tags: json, vue.js

I should download json file on button click. When I click, I make a request to api and the following response:

```json
{
  data: {…},
  status: 200,
  statusText: "",
  headers: {…},
  config: {…},
  …
}
```

but how can I download json file on button clicking with this response from backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library like [`downloadjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs)

import downloadjs in the the component where your button is.
attach a onClick event listenerr to your button and perform the following operation using downloadjs

```js
download(JSON.stringify(apiResponse), "apidata.json", "text/plain");
```